# Workflow immediately rejects document when "End on Document Change" is selected

Tags: 2010, workflow, content-approval

I have created a new "Approval SharePoint 2010" workflow for a document library.

When I select the "End on Document Change" option, it says it will "Automatically reject the document if it is changed before the workflow is completed."

The problem is that every document becomes immediately rejected. It says "Approval on  has ended because the item that the task process is running on was changed."

I am guessing there is something getting triggered that changes the document, but I am not sure what it could be.

What should I check?

I can't recreate the problem on a new document library, so I guess this is more of an academic question than an actual problem I am facing.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: I am also having the same problem

Comment: Granting permission on the item was causing the issue.